# Is it possible to select a specific <div> when another <div> which is not a parent is :hover in CSS3 only?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select a specific `<div>` when another `<div>` which is not a parent is `:hover`?

All that in HTML5/CSS3 only, without JS.

```html
<section>
  <div id=first></div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class=second></div>
</section>
```

As an example, i want `<div class=second>` to show when `<div id=first>` is `:hover`.

Comment: For some clarification, you want `div.second` to show, when `div.first` is `:hover`?

Comment: Yes, sorry first time posting here! 
That's exactly my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but only if the two elements have the same parent.
Using the `element1 ~ element2` [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp). For example:
HTML:

```
<div class="first">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
<span class="example-element"></span>
<div class="second">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first:hover ~ .second {
    /* styles */
}
```

If you need to select an element that does not have the same parent, you need to use javascript.

Comment: Got it, too bad, i'm limited to html5 and CSS3 for this...
Thanks for the fast answer, you saved me a lot of time trying to look for a non-existent solution !
Have a great weekend !

Comment: Glad I could help, you have a great weekend too!

Answer (score 0):

this is two ways to achive that, with click adding an `a` tag or with hover that its a little tricky

```css
.second{
  display:none;
}

#second:target {
  display:block;
}

#first a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
}

.disp1:hover + .disp2{
  display:block;
}

.disp2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="first"><a href="#second" >div one</a></div>
</section>

<section>
  <div id="second" class="second">div two</div>
</section>

<div class="disp1">first div</div>
<div class="disp1 disp2">second div</div>
```